# Safari slowdown issues

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, performance

Safari is quite slow when I open new tabs. I get a busy cursor, and I cannot interact with other tabs.

Is there any way to make it faster?

I have a 2010 MacBook Pro, MacOS 10.6.6, Safari 5.0.3.

Comment: What versions of OS X and Safari are you running?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: How much RAM does your mac have?

Answer (score 2):

Install clicktoflash or some other flash blocking thing.

Also disable java and other plugins. These are particularly useful for Safari 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good tips on [reviews.cnet.com](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10328447-263.html) on speeding up Safari.  Some of the tips are detailed below:

1. Try dragging the folder Icons -- where these icons are cached -- within the ~/Library/Safari folder to the trash and restarting Safari.
2. Try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` if you are experiencing slow launches, but note that you will lose some easily recoverable settings, such as whether or not tabbed browsing is enabled.
3. A blanket approach to deleting many of the potentially problem-causing items is the Reset Safari... command, available under the Safari menu in Safari. Note, however, that this command also deletes your browser history, personal data -- such as stored login passwords, search entries, cookies and more -- that you may not want to clear. Still, it's a good initial cleansing step.  On recent versions of Safari you can select the kinds of data you want to delete/keep.
4. Try temporarily disabling plugins to see if that's a potential cause.  Go to the Safari menu within Safari, and select Preferences.  Click on the Security tab and deselect 'Enable plug-ins'.  Restart Safari and see if the slowness has disappeared.  If it has then the problem is likely to be an errant plugin.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True, I think I was new to the site when I answered that.  I've amended the answer with some of the more likely causes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is to clear the cache and history, and restart Safari (and even your MacBook).